# Submit data by clicking on select list and refresh page

Tags: php

I need to update a column in database by just selecting an option from select list and refresh the page
On selecting an option from 
select list it should generate an alert
asking weather you want to do it or not
clicking on yes must refresh page and submit the selected value in database
while clicking on no must return on the same page

```
 <?php
    include_once('database.php');

    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reqapp where Lfrom >=(select lastlogin from   login ) and Status!='Approved'")
            or die(mysql_error()); 

?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Leave Manager</title>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="get" action="">

    <table border="1px" cellpadding="1px" cellspacing="1px" >
    <tr align="center">
    <td align="center">Employee code</td>

    <td align="center">Employee name</td>
    <td align="center">Email id</td>
    <td align="center"> Mobile number</td>
    <td align="center">Leave type</td>
    <td align="center">Leave from</td>
    <td align="center">Leave upto</td>
    <td align="center">Leave Reason</td>
    <td align="center">Action</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i=1;

    while($leave=mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
    {

      $demo=$leave['Empcode'];
      $lf=$leave['Lfrom'];


   ?> 
    <tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $leave['Empcode']; ?></td>
    <td align="center" ><?php echo $leave['Empname']; ?></td>
    <td align="center" ><?php echo $leave['Emailid']; ?></td>
    <td align="center" ><?php echo $leave['Mobileno']; ?></td>
    <td align="center" ><?php echo $leave['Ltype']; ?></td>
    <td align="center" ><?php echo $leave['Lfrom']; ?></td>
    <td align="center" ><?php echo $leave['Lto']; ?></td>
    <td align="center" ><?php echo $leave['Lreason']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><select name="action">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Approved">Approve</option>
                        <option value="Edit">Edit </option>
                        <option value="Rejected">Reject </option>

    </tr>
    <?php $i++;


       }


        if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
        {
        if(isset($_REQUEST['action']))
        $action=$_REQUEST['action'];


      {

     $querys=("update reqapp set Status='$action' where Empcode='$demo' and       Lfrom='$lf'");
     $r=mysql_query($querys) or die(mysql_error());

     }


    }


    ?>
    </table>
    </form>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: so the question would be?

Comment: we can understand that you might want to do something with a program, that's natural. what isn't working, what error messages are you getting, what have you tried?

Comment: You can easily do this with javascript using `onchange` and `confirm`.

Comment: Can't be done with php alone. You'll need to take help of javascript too. To get you started, look up `select onchange` and `window.confirm` keywords under javascript

Comment: can someone help me with javascript code

Comment: send me some code so that i can sort my problem out